# MUI 5 best practices for usage of sx property

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

in our new project we've transited to mui 5. I found that we are using sx prop much for custom layouts and components. there are many examples of such usage in documentation of mui itself. it looks a bit hard coded for me:

1. it's very similar to usage of style property for inline styling. how reuse of styles should be organized here?
2. it's not comfortable for debugging too since sx props has no name and it's hard to identify what component styles come from. is there any way to have sx prop named?

Will appreciate if somebody will share best practices how to organize style with mui 5 in proper way.

cheers.